# accessing variable from script tag in html file in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've only started working on javascript and React.js recently. I currently have a few script tags in my main.html file, and I need to be able to access some variables from these tags in my React.js components. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 5):

If you have defined the variables directly in your `<script>` tag, then they are global and **you should be able to simply reference them** from any of your React components.

That being said, **you should not do that**. This introduces a dependency that not only makes it very hard to reuse the component, but will also be a maintenance nightmare due to it's in-transparency.

Instead, when you render your root component, pass the **variable as a property and pass it on through your component tree** to the component that requires it. This way, only your root component depends on outside variables and the interfaces of your lower-level components are cleanly and transparently defined.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!